# POST parameters python

Tags: python, http, post, post-parameter

I need to view post parameters with python. The website in question has a post parameter of business_*number* where *number* changes after each successful action. I need to be able to get this number and then submit a POST request with a value.

A GET request does not give me the needed information. (I have tried with requests.) I have used a firefox addon called httprequester and used the "Submit" button and within the response is the information I need. I'm a real novice with HTTP :) so is there a way I can submit with Python (click the submit button) and then save the response in a variable that I will sort through.

Answer (score 0):

I used the requests module to solve my problem:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/